# Moving a Control By Mouse

Tags: c#

I am going to Moving a Button with Mouse , Everything is ok , but when I move mouse on button window , left and top of the button ( top-left corner) will locate at cursor pos .

I don't want this to occur . where is the bug in my code ?

```
private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        clicked = true;
    }

}

private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (clicked)
    {
        Point p = new Point();//in form coordinates
        p.X =  e.X + button1.Left;
        p.Y =  e.Y + button1.Top;
        button1.Left = p.X;
        button1.Top = p.Y ;

    }

}

private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    clicked = false;   
}
```

Comment: ClientToScreen and ScreenToClient coordinates

Answer (score 10):

This is all you need

```
    private Point MouseDownLocation;

    private void MyControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void MyControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            this.Left = e.X + this.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
            this.Top = e.Y + this.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found it...

here is the full code :

```
private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Point p = ConvertFromChildToForm(e.X, e.Y, button1);
        iOldX = p.X;
        iOldY = p.Y;
        iClickX = e.X;
        iClickY = e.Y;
        clicked = true;
    }

}

private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (clicked)
    {
        Point p = new Point();//in form coordinates
        p.X =  e.X + button1.Left;
        p.Y =  e.Y + button1.Top;
        button1.Left = p.X - iClickX;
        button1.Top = p.Y - iClickY;

    }

}

private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    clicked = false;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got it right, but just in case... if the problem is to position the cursor in the center of the button (or another component), you can achive it by considering the width and height:

```
 private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
      if (clicked) {
        Point p = new Point(); //in form coordinates
        p.X = e.X + button1.Left - (button1.Width/2);
        p.Y = e.Y + button1.Top - (button1.Height/2);
        button1.Left = p.X;
        button1.Top = p.Y;
      }
    }
```

Comment: No, maybe the mouse position in the  button  is (30,12);<br/> So We cannot say its  center of button.

Comment: Indeed, in some cases it won't remain exactly on the center. It was a simple solution for the problem. I think your first approach is good because the cursor remains in the same place while dragging.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is full code you need:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MoveButton
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool clicked = false;
    Point iOld = new Point();
    Point iClick = new Point();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private Point ConvertFromChildToForm(int x, int y, Control control)
    {
        Point p = new Point(x, y);
        control.Location = p;
        return p;
    }
    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Point p = ConvertFromChildToForm(e.X, e.Y, button1);
            iOld.X = p.X;
            iOld.Y = p.Y;
            iClick.X = e.X;
            iClick.Y = e.Y;
            clicked = true;
        }

    }

    private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (clicked)
        {
            Point p = new Point();//in form coordinates
            p.X = e.X + button1.Left;
            p.Y = e.Y + button1.Top;
            button1.Left = p.X - iClick.X;
            button1.Top = p.Y - iClick.Y;

        }

    }

    private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        clicked = false;
    }
   }
}
```