# During runtime create and move picturebox

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB 2010

I am trying to create a program in which during runtime I can create a new picturebox with mousedown and then have the ability to move each picturebox created. I feel as if I am close, could anyone help me out?

```
Private Sub PictureBox2_Mousedown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
    Dim newPictureBox As New PictureBox

    newPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Blair\Desktop\table8.jpg")
    newPictureBox.Visible = True
    newPictureBox.Top = 0
    newPictureBox.Width = 200
    newPictureBox.Height = 200
    newPictureBox.Left = 100
    newPictureBox.BringToFront()
    newPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

    If IsDragging Then
        Dim EndPoint As Point = newPictureBox.PointToScreen(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
        IsClick = False
        newPictureBox.Left += (EndPoint.X - StartPoint.X)
        newPictureBox.Top += (EndPoint.Y - StartPoint.Y)
        StartPoint = EndPoint
        LastPoint = EndPoint
    End If


    'add control to form
    Controls.Add(newPictureBox)

End Sub
```

ISSUE: The picturebox populates but it does not have the ability to move/drag on mousedown

Comment: so what is not working?

Comment: Once the picturebox is visible it does not drag/move on mousedown

Comment: Check these out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662363/how-to-move-a-control-on-mousemove-in-runtime and http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/709121/Move-and-Resize-Controls-on-a-Form-at-Runtime-With.

Comment: Great references but my issue is not so much making the picturebox move. That can be done with the code I provided (e.g. If IsDragging Then) My issue is that I cannot create new pictureboxes and make them drag/move during runtime. It is only displaying the picturebox.

Comment: You need to use `AddHandler` to wire up the MouseMove() event of your dynamic PictureBox.

Comment: There hasn't been any activity on this post for a couple weeks. Please let us know how you solved this problem or if you require further help on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not be exactly what you are looking for as it doesn't use all of your original variables but I took a stab at creating a simple example for you to learn from. To test this just create a new blank form (Form1) and without adding any controls just copy/paste this code over top of the form code and run it.

If you click anywhere on the form it will create a new picturebox and you can move it around with the mouse as long as you hold down the left mouse button. When you let go of the left mouse button it will stop moving the picturebox and you can either:

a) click on another blank space on the form to create a new picturebox and move it where you want or,

b) you can click on one of the existing pictureboxes you created earlier and move it to a different location.

Comments are included to help you understand better how it works.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim oDragPoint As Point = Nothing
    Dim oCurrentPictureBox As PictureBox = Nothing

    Private Sub Event_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
        If TypeOf sender Is PictureBox Then
            ' Move existing picturebox
            oCurrentPictureBox = sender
            oCurrentPictureBox.BringToFront()
            oDragPoint = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        Else
            ' Create a new picturebox
            oCurrentPictureBox = New PictureBox

            oCurrentPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Blair\Desktop\table8.jpg")
            oCurrentPictureBox.Location = Me.PointToClient(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position)
            oCurrentPictureBox.Width = 200
            oCurrentPictureBox.Height = 200
            oCurrentPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

            ' Add events to the new picturebox we just created so that it can be moved again later
            AddHandler oCurrentPictureBox.MouseDown, AddressOf Event_MouseDown
            AddHandler oCurrentPictureBox.MouseMove, AddressOf Event_MouseMove
            AddHandler oCurrentPictureBox.MouseUp, AddressOf Event_MouseUp

            ' Add picturebox to form
            Me.Controls.Add(oCurrentPictureBox)

            ' Bring picturebox to front after it has been added to the form to ensure it is on top of all other controls in the controls collection
            oCurrentPictureBox.BringToFront()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Event_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
        If oCurrentPictureBox IsNot Nothing Then
            ' Move picture box wherever the mouse moves
            Dim oMouseCursorPoint As Point = Me.PointToClient(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position)
            oCurrentPictureBox.Location = New Point(oMouseCursorPoint.X - oDragPoint.X, oMouseCursorPoint.Y - oDragPoint.Y)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Event_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
        ' Drop picturebox and stop moving it around
        oCurrentPictureBox = Nothing
        oDragPoint = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice answer example. 
when creating dynamically, once you have added the required handles i.e. picturebox1_click-.click scenario anywhere after the object being created you can do whatever you want. so if you want the picturebox to be clickable and moveable use event handlers 
like so 
public sub picturebox_click(sender as object,e as eventargs)
do whatever you want to do when user clicks the picturebox.
dim p as picturebox= trycast(sender,picturebox)
from here you can hook it up. when user clicks p=sender etc.
this way whatever image they click is the one that will move or do whatever, to show the user they are over the image to be clicked you can add borderstyle borderstyle=bordrstyle.3dfixed as example then in the click event you created you have borderstyle=borderstyle.none this lets them know the image is under mouse. anyhow I am makin something right now that does this so wanted to share what I discovered as a Learnerguy

Here is an example I am using 
 Dim pan As New Panel
        pan.Name = "Panel" & Convert.ToString(count)

```
    pan.BackColor = Color.Black
    AddHandler pan.MouseEnter, AddressOf pan_MouseEnter
    AddHandler pan.Click, AddressOf pan_Click
    AddHandler pan.MouseDown, AddressOf pan_MouseDown
    AddHandler pan.MouseMove, AddressOf pan_MouseMove
    AddHandler pan.MouseUp, AddressOf pan_MouseUp

    Form2.Panel1.Controls.Add(pan)
    Dim gdonopen As New OpenFileDialog
    gdonopen.ShowDialog
    pan.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(gdonopen.FileName)
    pan.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
    objCtrl = pan
```

add required events and that will give you a clickable movable panel-switch panel to picturebox.
Enjoy your day fellow programmers!
-Learnerguy