# Possibly missing properties in MouseEventsArg e

Tags: c#, winforms, events, visual-studio-2013, mouse

So I am trying to set up a function that allows me to move objects around a windows form with the mouse and using MouseEventsArg e seems to be that way to go.  I have been trying to use properties such as .button, .location, .X and .Y because that is what I see pop up most often when I do a Google search for my problem. But I keep getting errors telling me that those properties are not defined. I go to look at MouseEventsArg e and all I see is .buttonleft, .buttonright, .button and so on. Is there something that I am missing or  I just being very stupid.

```
 private void mouseLocation;

 private void  button1_mousedown (object sender,       MouseEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons. Left)
   {
     Mouse Location = e.Location;
   }

private void button1_MouseMove  (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
   {
       this.Left = e.X + this.Left - MouseLocation.X;
       this.Top = e.Y + this.Top - MouseLocation.Y;
    }
}
```

(Sorry if this looks bad, I am doing this from my phone.)

Comment: Are you looking at the correct [MouseEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) class?  Otherwise, post your code.

Comment: Ok, I'm posting form phone. I'll post the code in a sec.

Comment: Code works (ignoring the glaring typos).  How you are getting buttonLeft and buttonRight properties is very unclear.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662363/how-to-move-a-control-on-mousemove-in-runtime ? Seems quite similar, both talking about controls, and moving them. May or may not help the asker.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`MouseEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) NOT `MouseEventArg`

> #### MouseEventArgs Class
>
> Provides data for the [`MouseUp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup(v=vs.110).aspx), [`MouseDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown(v=vs.110).aspx), and [`MouseMove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove(v=vs.110).aspx) events.

Comment: It is MouseEventsArgs. I'm sorry. Again I'm doing g this from my phone at the moment. I edited it

Comment: @Echo_ghost Are you using the System.Windows.Forms namespace?