# How to change textbox location at the click of a mouse in live mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a `TextBox` in live mode and want to add that its location can be changed with the mouse. The problem I have is that after generating a `TextBox`, I can't execute code on it.

This is my code:

```cs
int Naslov_rnd;

private void Naslov_p_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Naslov_rnd++;

    TextBox tb = new TextBox();

    tb.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    tb.Width = 200;
    tb.Height = 20;
    tb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

    tb.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
    tb.ForeColor = Color.White;

    tb.Name = "Naslov_" + Naslov_rnd.ToString();
    tb.Text = "Dodajte Vaš naslov";
    tb.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12);

    VizitKartica.Controls.Add(tb);
    elementi_lista.AddItem(tb.Name);

    tb.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(tb_MouseMove);
    tb.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(tb_MouseDown);
}

protected void tb_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
}

protected void tb_MouseMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
}
```

Comment: Move the declaraton to class level! Or, if you want to use one of the tb events cast `sender` to  `TextBox`!

Comment: "I created a textbox in **live mode**" I think you meant to say that you created the TextBox *at runtime* or *programmatically*. I've never heard it called "live mode" and thought there was some new C# feature I was unaware of.

Comment: Your tb_Mouse... methods should be MouseEventArgs instead of just EventArgs.  It's unclear what you plan on doing in those methods.  Try [how to move a control on mousemove in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10662363/719186)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at the documentation for [`TextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). In the [Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=netframework-4.8#examples) section, they call [`SuspendLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout?view=netframework-4.8) prior to changing the `TextBox`'s properties and call [`ResumeLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout?view=netframework-4.8) and [`PerformLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.performlayout?view=netframework-4.8) after adding the form to the `Controls` collection. Note that instead of calling `PerformLayout()`, you can just do `ResumeLayout(true)`.

> The `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` methods are used in tandem to suppress multiple `Layout` events while you adjust multiple attributes of the control. For example, you would typically call the `SuspendLayout` method, then set the `Size`, `Location`, `Anchor`, or `Dock` properties of the control, and then call the `ResumeLayout` method to enable the changes to take effect.

Also note:

> You must set the `Multiline` property to `true` to adjust the height of the `TextBox` control. You can adjust the height by setting the `Size` property.

I would change your `Naslov_p_Click` handler to:

```cs
int Naslov_rnd;

private void Naslov_p_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    VizitKartica.SuspendLayout(); // Call before changing TextBox properties

    tb.Location = new Point(0, 0);

    tb.Multiline = true; // Set before changing width/height
    tb.Size = new Size(200, 20); // Use Size property

    tb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

    tb.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
    tb.ForeColor = Color.White;

    tb.Name = "Naslov_" + Naslov_rnd.ToString();;
    tb.Text = "Dodajte Vaš naslov";
    tb.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12);

    VizitKartica.Controls.Add(tb);
    elementi_lista.AddItem(tb.Name);

    VizitKartica.ResumeLayout(true); // Call after adding it to the Controls collection

    tb.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(tb_MouseMove);
    tb.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(tb_MouseDown);
}
```

### Edit

If you declare a variable in a method, you can't use it outside of the method due to it having a local scope. Declaring the `tb` variable outside of the `Naslov_p_Click` method will allow you access it from other methods:

```cs
int Naslov_rnd;
TextBox tb; // Declare it here

private void Naslov_p_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tb = new TextBox();

    // ...
}

protected void tb_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) 
    { 
        tb.Left = e.X + tb.Left; 
        tb.Top = e.Y + tb.Top; 
    }
}

protected void tb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) 
    { 
        Point MouseDownLocation = e.Location; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I need change tb location with mouse,but I can't control  tb with another void.

I try

    ` protected void tb_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                tb.Left = e.X + tb.Left;
                tb.Top = e.Y + tb.Top;
            }
            }`

    `protected  void tb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Point MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
            }
        }`

But  tb is not defined

Comment: So create the `TextBox` outside of the `Naslov_p_Click` method. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I updated my answer. I'd appreciate you removing the downvote.

Comment: Now I have a new problem. When I create 2 or more TBs and try to move one of the previous ones, the last one I created disappears and the others can't move. Can you ever fix it?

Comment: @BPSK Post a new question with the relevant code and post a link to it and I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57564680/how-to-change-textbox-location-in-runtime