# How to change TextBox location at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating `TextBoxes` at runtime and add an `EventHandler` to eac, but I can only move the last one created, when I try to move a previous one, it disappears.

This is my code:

```
int Naslov_rnd;
TextBox tb;

private void Naslov_p_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Naslov_rnd++;

    tb = new TextBox();
    VizitKartica.SuspendLayout();

    tb.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    tb.Multiline = true;
    tb.Size = new Size(200, 20);
    tb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    tb.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
    tb.ForeColor = Color.White;
    tb.Name = "Naslov_" + Naslov_rnd.ToString(); ;
    tb.Text = "Dodajte Vaš naslov";
    tb.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12);

    VizitKartica.Controls.Add(tb);
    elementi_lista.AddItem(tb.Name);

    VizitKartica.ResumeLayout(true); Controls collection

      tb.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(tb_MouseMove);
    tb.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(tb_MouseDown);
}

protected void tb_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        tb.Left = e.X + tb.Left;
        tb.Top = e.Y + tb.Top;
    }
}

protected void tb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Point MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of this: `TextBox tb;`  You have to cast the "sender" to a TextBox and use that control.

Comment: What is `VizitKartica`? A panel?

Comment: in this case VizitKartica is name for panel

Comment: Your question is unclear. In what way would you like to be able to move previously-added text boxes? Where is the code you've already tried, for the purpose of doing that? What _specifically_ are you having trouble figuring out? Please provide a good [mcve], along with precise and detailed answers to these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@LarsTech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719186/larstech) said, you cannot make one `TextBox` object point to all of the `TextBoxes` that will be created, a simple and effective solution to this is to use the sender object.

The `EventHandler` provides you with an argument wich will get passed to the method, and it will point to the control that caused the event to be fired.

Since we know that all the `TextBoxes` are sharing the same event and they are all `TextBoxes`, we can type-cast the sender object to the `TextBox` class and then use it.

Here is how :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int Naslov_rnd;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Naslov_rnd++;

        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        VizitKartica.SuspendLayout();

        tb.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        tb.Multiline = true;
        tb.Size = new Size(200, 20);
        tb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        tb.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
        tb.ForeColor = Color.White;
        tb.Name = "Naslov_" + Naslov_rnd.ToString();
        tb.Text = "Dodajte Vaš naslov";
        tb.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12);

        VizitKartica.Controls.Add(tb);

        VizitKartica.ResumeLayout(true); 

        tb.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(tb_MouseMove);
        tb.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(tb_MouseDown);
    }

    protected void tb_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb2 = (TextBox) sender;
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            tb2.Left = e.X + tb2.Left;
            tb2.Top = e.Y + tb2.Top;
        }
    }

    protected void tb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Point MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helped you and what you are looking for.